# Why is Xcode's Info.plist asking for my Astrological Sign?

Tags: xcode, plist

Somehow, the Info.plist of my project no longer displays the correct drop-down for the Keys:

[image: Broken Plist]
It's just got those 6 entries for all of the rows; including new rows added. I've tried restarting Xcode... and I've even tried setting 'Probability of success' to be 100%... :/

Amusing as it may be... does anyone have any idea why this has happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the property list editor. There's a menuitem called "Property List Type". Mouse over this. There's a bunch of sub-types. You probably got yours set to "Example Structure" or "Example Structure (with full Zodiac defined)". You want to re-select Info.plist.

[image]